# Promote Method returned an invalid Value for the Distributed transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, msdtc

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in SQL Server with some parameters and the Procedure is suppose to return a message telling me whether it worked or not.

I have double checked my code and it all seems correct but I keep getting an error saying

`The promote method returned an invalid value for the distributed transaction`

When the call is executed. I could really use some help.

All my research says that it is related to the `MSDTC`. However, I have tried calling the procedure with the same values and same code in another Controller in my application, it's an MVC app, and I get the right message back without the error.

Am I wrong to assume that it is not the `MSDTC` because if that was the case, neither calls to the database would work regardless of the Controller.

Comment: I am also receiving this error, have you come to a resolution?

Comment: I found a work around. Is your SQL Server 2005 or 2008?

Comment: It is 2008 and/or 2012

Comment: That's good. If you tell me exactly what scenario is giving the error I can better assist you because in my situation there were calls to two different databases within that same TransactionScope and caused the error. I just ended up making the calls to each database separately and only one within the TransactionScope to solve the error.

Comment: There are 3 different EF contexts that are established within a single transaction, it would be a real pain to refactor it, but it may be my only option.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you can enable the MS DTC then you will not get the error follow these directions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753620.aspx